# Source Code available for System.Xml.Linq.XNode?

Tags: c#, open-source

I'm trying to figure out how `XNode.ReadFrom(XmlReader reader)` works, but I can't find source code available for the `XNode` class online.

Comment: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow*

Comment: ummm... can't help but notice "source code" isn't in that list... and I'm not asking for a recommendation.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs: Doesn't "other off-site resource" cover it?

Comment: "Does it exist?" shouldn't be covered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's available in the .NET reference source repository:

https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Xml.Linq/System/Xml/Linq/XLinq.cs#L1457

Comment: Thank you sir.  Worth the downvotes :)